# Warning screen on sqllite cursor while debugging

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm making an android application that loads a byte array from a database. But while I'm debugging I constantly get the following screen. 
I can continue debugging and my application runs fine, but I just wonder why I get this screen.

[image]
Any ideas?

I get the following in my logcat without placing a breakpoint : [image]

Comment: what is your problem? Is there any sort of error in logcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have source code for SqliteCursor.java . You are trying to debug code that is present in the framework of Android rather than your own app